# JSF managed property injection null inside REST resource

Tags: java, jsf, javabeans

I have a REST resource class (so the one listening for incoming REST connections from the web) which needs to access a managed bean library controller.
Upon invocation however I get a null pointer exception.

```
@ApplicationPath("webresources")
@Path("/record")
@Stateless
public class RecordResource
{
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{libraryController}") // this references the @ManagedBean named libraryController
    private LibraryController libraryController;

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadWeb(InputStream inputStream)
    {
      //Null exception below !
      getLibraryController().function();
    }

    public LibraryController getLibraryController()
    {
        return libraryController;
    }

    public void setLibraryController(LibraryController libraryController)
    {
        this.libraryController = libraryController;
    }
}
```

The getters/setters are ok so I don't know why the proper constructor for LibraryController is not called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The injection fails because the client class is not a `@ManagedBean`, therefore the container has no notion of the JSF context inside `RecordResource`.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17356143/injecting-jsf-managed-bean-to-a-ejb) for further clarification.

As a workaround, consider to use an `@EJB` controller and inject it by means of `@EJB` annotation. Otherwise please explain what's the business logic behind this design.

Comment: this makes sense, also I just realized @ManagedBean annotations are goind to be deprecated in favour of CDI injection. So I'll have to review all the current structure of this project.